# Pyglet/OpenGL point sprites

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I decided to use pyglet and opengl to make a 3D FPS game. I am trying to create a Doom-like effect where certain images are kept 2D (always face the camera) in a 3D environment. A few google searches later, and I come across point sprites. Currently trying to implement these. Here is my code:

```
playerimg = pyglet.image.load(r"img\front.png").texture

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, playerimg.id)
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)
glTexEnvi(GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE)

x,y,z = 0,1,0
glBegin(GL_POINTS)
glVertex3f(x+2,y,z)
glVertex3f(x,y,z)
glVertex3f(x,y+2,z)
glVertex3f(x+2,y+2,z)
glEnd()
```

I get no errors when I use this code, however, the image does not appear anywhere on screen. I have already implemented (camera) movement and rotation, but I never see the image.

Comment: Also got a previous question similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911640/rotate-3d-image-batches-to-make-them-2d

Comment: @Torxed this question is to achieve the same effect, but in a completely different way.

Comment: Well aware, thought people might be interested in seeing how you came to this conclusion, also they might not be able to solve this problem but perhaps the other one - and vice versa. So this is not a "marked as duplicate".. It's more of a "hey chick this attempt as well and see if you can have a crack at it if this is impossible" :)